# Direct copy Ramdisk image to Ramdisk device

Tags: linux, ramdisk

Right, so I've got a Ramdisk image on a mounted device at, say, /mnt/sda1/Ramdisk.img . I want to copy the raw data directly to a ramdisk device at /dev/ram0, in such a way that there will be no need to use mke2fs: I could mount the image and device and find that both are identical.

Ideally this would use only linux commands.

My ideas so far: Mounting the image on a loopback and using basic IO to put the data from one device into the other. I could probably do this with C.
Also, somehow finding the physical address of the ramdisk device and using linux or C commands to put the file directly into the memory.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I know that the kernel somehow flags memory which was used for ramdisks so the system does not reclaim it. Anyone know where these flags are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of copy command is going to require a partition and filesystem at the destination.  However, [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) can work at the disk or partition level, by just specifying the disk (eg /dev/sda) or partition (eg (dev/sda1) level.  So in theory, you could do

```
dd if=ramdisk_image_file of=/dev/ram0
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed.